# Ubuntu 18 crash when opening google chrome

Tags: 18.04, google-chrome, amd-graphics, crash

So i have a problem with my ubuntu 18.04 LTS,when i turn on my laptop and login to ubuntu and when i directly open google chrome after logged in, my screen become unresponsive and suddenly goes black, but the power indicator is still on. So i have to restart my laptop and wait a few minutes or so then i can open google chrome and function normally.Does anybody experience the same? Is it the bug on ubuntu 18.04 LTS or is it the chrome?

note: I'm on Asus AMD series

**Edit:**
`total 8` 
`drwxrwsrwt  2 root   whoopsie 4096 Nov 14 22:11 .`
`drwxr-xr-x 15 root   root     4096 Nov 10 18:49 ..`
`----------  1 iqbale whoopsie    0 Nov 14 22:11 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash`

**free -h**

`total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available`
`Mem:           5,8G        3,3G        227M        376M        2,2G        1,9G`
`Swap:           15G         13M         15G`

**vm.swappiness** 
`vm.swappiness = 60`

Comment: Please clarify your release(s).  Ubuntu uses *yy* releases only for specialist *snap* based releases for IoT appliances/devices or cloud based use (having done so since 2016). Main releases use *yy.mm* such as used by server & desktops releases.  Ubuntu Core 18 is a different product to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Sorry, i was using ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema here's my crash

`total 8`
`drwxrwsrwt  2 root   whoopsie 4096 Nov 14 22:11 .`
`drwxr-xr-x 15 root   root     4096 Nov 10 18:49 ..`
`----------  1 iqbale whoopsie    0 Nov 14 22:11 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash `

Comment: Your problem is with Chrome. Do you have the current version? Do you have any extensions or apps installed? Does the same problem occur with Firefox? Show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: @heynnema no i havent tried with Firefox